# How to use datasets in rhpam?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, dataset, jbpm, business-process-management

I want to use a (SQL/Mongodb) database in a task in business process in RHPAM. I have gone through the datasets and datasources in the rhpam but still have some questions regarding that like:

1. how to use datasets and datasources
2. how to link datasets and datasources to a business process?
3. how to retrieve values from datasets4) i want to use a mongodb database...am i be able to connect to mongodb using dataset...If yes, then how?

Need some help in this..Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the attached gif on how to create a dataset in jbpm/rhpam.

[image: dataset_gif_img]